# DB2 - Restrict a DB User to just use Select, Insert and Update Operations

Tags: sql, db2

i want to restrict a db2 user to just do some operations like select,insert and update operations. Is there a way in DB2 to do it? i am newbie to db2. Please let me know 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you use [`GRANT`](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sql_granttableorviewprivileges.htm) for. Examples from the manual:

```
GRANT SELECT ON DSN8A10.EMP TO SOME_USER;
GRANT UPDATE (EMPNO, WORKDEPT) ON TABLE DSN8A10.EMP TO SOME_USER;
```

In general, in SQL databases, you don't restrict privileges, you grant them, starting from almost no privileges.